# Is there any way to calculate the voltage & current rating on an unmarked component?

Tags: maximum-ratings

I just acquired an assortment of electronic components, many of which either have no way of identifying ratings at all (ie resistors) and some ie (transistors) where there has either been no printed identifier or it has worn away.

I know they are cheap to replace, it's the question that interests me, not the products.

Comment: If you have a bunch of the same part, you could test some until they break, then de-rate the remaining ones from wherever the tested ones failed.

Comment: Passive components like resistors are pretty much identifiable by their physical size, assuming you can read, or measure, the resistance value. Active components is a lot harder and as @ThePhoton mentions, destructive testing is about your only way. Even then though, these things have so many properties, you would be guessing at most of them if you do not have some very specific test equipment.

Comment: This might help with resistors: [Power ratings of common throughole resistors.  Beginner's field recognition guide.](http://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-guess-power-rating-of-throughole-resistors.html)

Comment: For transistors, it's probably good enough to get a $10-$20 transistor checker off of ebay. They work reasonably well and are quite cheap. Some can identify capacitors and resistors (and even inductors in a few cases.) An oscilloscope with the right setup (low voltage transformer) can also help: [Component Tester](http://www.qsl.net/g4usp/Component%20tester/Simple%20scope%20component%20tester%20adapter.pdf).

Comment: A transistor checker will tell you which pin is which and what the gain is (at a nominal test current), but not the maximum voltage, current or power ratings surely?

Comment: If I find a part with an undecipherable or missing identifier I throw it away. Not worth the risk of it failing or performing unexpectedly.

Comment: SHow me a photo of some example parts and I'll demonstrate with experience how to find match identify parts using my answer deleted by Dave Twiddly Dee

Answer (score 2):

Physical size will give you a good idea of resistor power capability.

Transistors and diodes can be tested to breakdown without damage in some cases using a curve tracer or equivalent experimental techniques, but unprotected MOSFET gates can be damaged, and possibly bipolar transistors as well.

There is no sure way to determine ceramic capacitor voltage ratings, and size may be misleading since older parts were much larger for the same ratings. You can plot capacitance vs. bias voltage.

You can measure inductor saturation current and estimate current rating from the size and resistance. Measuring core losses at various frequencies takes more equipment.

There is a little open board, sort-of open source AVR-based tester that will identify various active and passive parts and give you values. Search for GM328, should be less than $10. Image from ali.

[image]

I can't imagine any of this being of much value though, valuable parts will likely have markings and if you have enough cheap parts to be valuable the packaging will have markings.